# Find and execute multiple scripts in parallel

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, find

G'day,

I have tried to solve this problem all morning but have not had success. I would like to search for certain scripts in a particular folder and execute them all in parallel. The scripts have different names, but all end with "run.sh". Below what I have tried without success.

The first approach was to use find in combination with -execdir. This works, however, the scripts are executed in a sequantial fashion. I want all scripts to be executed simultaneously (parallel). There seems to be no option to achieve this with -execdir

```
find . -name "*run.sh" -type f -execdir 'nohup' {} '&' \;
```

Then, I tried using xargs because there is has a parallel option (-P). I have not tried the parallel option yet, because I am unable to get xargs to run the scripts in their respective subfolders. The commands below execute all scripts, but do that in the folder I am running the command in, therefore the scripts themselves do not work. The scripts have to be executed in their own subfolders. In the above example, -execdir is doing that as opposed to -exec. How do I achieve that with xargs?

```
nohup find . -name "*run.sh" -type f | xargs -0 -I{} bash -c f\ \{\}
```

or

```
nohup find . -name "*run.sh" -type f | xargs -0 -I{} bash -c "f {}"
```

or

```
nohup find . -name "*run.sh" -type f | xargs -0 -I{} bash -c "./{}"
```

I am really frustrated and am hoping that there is somebody out there that can help. 
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

Inspired by choroba's answer:

```
find . -iname '*run.sh' -printf 'cd %h; ./%f\0' | xargs -L1 -0 -P0 bash -c
```

You can use `-printf` to build the command line. `%h` is the directory where the file is located, and `%f` is the name of the file without the path (the basename). The `-P` option enables parallelism in `xargs`, and `-L1 -0` makes it use one null-terminated line of input per command.

Answer (score 1):

What about creating the command lines you want to run, then running them?

```
find . -name '*run.sh' -type f -exec \
    echo 'c={}; cd ${c%/*} && nohup "./${c##*/}" &' \;
```

If the output is what you want, just append `| bash` and run again.